# Android white image is not white when minSdkVersion="10"

Tags: android, colors, image

I have an ImageView in Layout. Layaout background is white (@android:color/white) and in ImageView contain a *.png picture. But white color on this picture is not the same white as in layout it is little gray.[a http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg513/scaled.php?server=513&filename=1325684647707.jpg&res=medium](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg513/scaled.php?server=513&filename=1325684647707.jpg&res=medium)
I tried to change the format of the file, different color depth etc but it doesn't help. Then I remove minSdkVersion from manifest and it solve the problem. But I really need this tag in manifest. Does anybody have any idea which format of picture or what I have to change to fix it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar quention: [Image does not show completely white despite it's correctly white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485410/image-does-not-show-completely-white-despite-its-correctly-white)
Copied from there:

The cause of the problem is that regardless of the original bitmap format in the APK files all bitmaps are compressed (in my case into indexed 256-color! wtf?).

*I couldn't find the way to prevent it, so if anyone knows the proper solution, please tell.*

However, I found two solutions for the white color problem.

1) **Per-bitmap:** Say, we have a drawable bitmap resource called `@drawable/mypng`, which causes the problem. We need to add an additional XML drawable drawable/mypng_nofilter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/mypng"
    android:filter="false"
/>
```

and use `@drawable/mypng_nofilter` instead.

2) **For entire activity:** In activity onCreate method we need to add

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
```

Now the window has 16-bit color depth and all bitmaps appear "properly" white.

Again, I would prefer to have 32-bit color depth, but I don't know how to control compile-time image compression.

Answer (score -1):

instead of using default white color. redefine the white color in you xml and use the same

Create colors.xml under res-> value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources><color name="white">#ffffff</color> </resources>
```

Use this white color in you xml by `@color/white"` example `android:background="@color/white"`

Comment: This is not the problem. The @android:color/white is real white. The problem is that the picture with white background is shown as gray (as you can see in the screen shot)