# Image does not show completely white despite it's correctly white

Tags: android, colors, rgb

For a splashscreen I use an image which contains a white background (pure white - checked in Photoshop). For some reason it shows a slight green bg vs. the activity's default white bg - as marked in the screenshot. Only in some devices, like the

[image: ImageView graphic shows now white background despite the image uses white]

I add this as single view in a frame layout to the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Any idea? I read about RGB888 vs. RGB565 issues, but couldn't find a proper solution.

Note: I sure could make change the white in the image to transparent, but would prefer to understand the problem and find a proper solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is really annoying. I wonder, why so few people encountered this problem as it should appear on all 32-bit displays.

You mentioned right about RGB888 format. The cause of the problem is that regardless of the original bitmap format in the APK files all bitmaps are compressed (in my case into indexed 256-color! wtf?).

*I couldn't find the way to prevent it, so if anyone knows the proper solution, please tell.*

However, I found two solutions for the white color problem.

1) **Per-bitmap:** Say, we have a drawable bitmap resource called `@drawable/mypng`, which causes the problem. We need to add an additional XML drawable drawable/mypng_nofilter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/mypng"
    android:filter="false"
/>
```

and use `@drawable/mypng_nofilter` instead.

2) **For entire activity:** In activity onCreate method we need to add

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
```

Now the window has 16-bit color depth and all bitmaps appear "properly" white.

Again, I would prefer to have 32-bit color depth, but I don't know how to control compile-time image compression.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue by changing the `Bitmap.CompressFormat` type to `PNG` instead of `JPEG`:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.nouv);
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with network loaded images. I solved the issue by disabling bitmap filter. Since I do not have the issue on ICS and newer devices, I turned off the bitmap filter only for pre-ICS devices. Following is the code I used (setting network loaded bitmap to the ImageView.)

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources(), bitmap);
bitmapDrawable.setFilterBitmap(false);
imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

After using all the solutions in the Stackoverflow. 
From changing `android:src` to `app:srcCompact` and many other solutions.
The thing which helped me was my image was inside **drawable-anydpi** and I moved the image from **drawable-anydpi** to **drawable** and it worked for me after 2 hours of research.

P.S: It might help someone too that's why I put it over here. :)

Answer (score -1):

As your image only have a picture in its middle, I would advise you to set:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

It will crop some part of your picture, at left and right, but will use the whole screen...

Answer (score -1):

You can also define a background to your FrameLayout or your ImageView using the color of your picture (which seems to be F8FCF8):

android:background="#F8FCF8"

Comment: As mentioned, the used image does have a pure #FFFFFF background. The greenish background is generated when Android adds the image - then it's visible on the screenshot.

Comment: Hum... that's weird. I've never seen that. Then maybe try the first solution?

Comment: Not an option, can't crop as it fills the lower part (the example above is cut for demonstration).